# How to dockerize nginx and another server in separate docker-compose files?

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

I have a reactjs app which I want to server through nginx. The app makes API requests a node.js Express server. I decided to dockerize nginx together with static website files (from reactjs app) in one docker-compose file. I created another docker-compose file for Express server. The containers are currently on my laptop and are using `localhost`. I haven't been able to get them to work for a long time and there's unfortunately not much information about this on the internet. (the website and Express server work when not inside Docker).

First of all I created a new docker network:

`docker network create --driver bridge appstore-net`

This is my docker-compose file for website and nginx:

```
version: '3.5'

services:
  appstore-front:
    container_name: appstore-front-production
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-prod
    ports:
      - '80:80'
    networks:
      - appstore-net
    external_links:
      - appstore-bl-server-production

networks:
  appstore-net:
    external: true
```

This is my docker-compose file for Express server:

```
version: '3'
services:
  appstore-bl-server:
    container_name: appstore-bl-server-production
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-prod
      context: .
    volumes:
      - ".:/usr/src/app"
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    networks:
      - appstore-net

networks:
  appstore-net:
    external: true
```

This is my nginx configuration:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;

  #Docker DNS
  resolver 127.0.0.11;

  server_name localhost;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/appstore.access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/appstore.error.log;

  location / {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index  index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
  }

  location /api {
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

      #hack to prevent nginx to resolve container's host on start up
      set $docker_host "appstore-bl-server";
      proxy_pass http://$docker_host:3000;
  }

  error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
  location = /50x.html {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
  }
}
```

As you can see I'm using docker DNS resolver as well as creating "passing proxy" to URL consisting of Express container name.

How can I make it work?

---

**EDIT:** I found 2 issues that could've been the reason:

1) `external_links` needs to refer to container name, not container service.

2) `docker_host` variable in nginx needs to refer to service name, not container name.

With these corrections the setup works (corrected the values in the OP as well).